# Is it possible to use thousands delimiters in OBIEE 11g Dashboard Prompts?

Tags: obiee

Is it possible to use thousands delimiters in OBIEE 11g Dashboard Prompts?
I need this when the end user is typing numbers in a Numeric Dashboard Prompt , as he/she type numbers , the ',' thousands delimiter appear on that input box  ( not in the analysis with formatting ! ).

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not without using a serious amount of JavaScript and that is definitely not recommendable.

A user's input into a prompt is just data entry. Don't waste time, maintenance effort and your ability to upgrade without issues for rather pointless demands like that.

Comment: No problem. Any time.